# An exploitable buffer overflow in Python's strcpy()

Tags: python, buffer-overflow, python-internals

How can one exploit a buffer overflow in Python.

I have the following code:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = cdll.msvcrt
a = c_char_p("Here's a string that has 60 characters, 61 if you count null")
b = c_char_p("What do I put here to inject code?")
a = libc.strcpy(a, b)
print "Well, that didn't do anything"
```

What do I put in `b` to inject code into the program? I exploited overflows in C before, but I can't even make it crash (the same program in C does crash with the same input).

What's wrong? How can I exploit unsafe code in Python's use of C functions?

Comment: Generally this requires a `b` pointer to some memory such that strcpy would "overwrite" some data that is used (usually run) later. See [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Comment: @user2864740 `c_char_p` is a pointer to memory, isn't it?

Comment: It needs to be a *specific* address to memory such that the overflow affects something (in an intended/observable manner).

Comment: It's very hard to do some controlled damage with buffer overflows in dynamic languages. You usually have no control, where which objects is in memory. With your ctypes-example, you can perhaps overwrite some ctypes variables, but hardly control anything inside python.

Comment: Python (and other dynamic languages) usually use the heap to store values.  The exact address is very difficult to predict, many of the exploits around strcpy overwrite the stack or static data areas, which is more predictable (although still not standard).  The heap will contain areas of unused or defunct memory, which is less likely on the stack.  An added complication is that Python (and others) does its own heap management, not using the C RTL.  On Windows Python now uses a lower level still (see `VirtualAlloc`).

Comment: @cdarke So, is this a definite no? Because I did see that you do get an address when allocating a string. What can I do?

Comment: Of course you get an address, but you have no idea what you would overwrite.  What I don't understand is why you want to do this.  Exploits on Python would be a) Version dependant b) Implementation dependant c) Unethical.

Comment: @cdarke I, personally, use `CPython [original] 2.7.9`. Why unethical? I program a system of virtual machines, written in Python, which is supposed to be hacked. One of the features I'd like to have is buffer overflow, so the user could exploit it. I could fake one and program it myself, but I thought that if it is possible, using `ctypes` to implement unsafe code in Python could be both perfect (as it is the most realistic, as the real thing) and expanding my knowledge.

Comment: OK, in that case Python is a poor target.  I think the best you could do is to write a Python module in C (using the Python API) and do the usual unsafe thing there.  Its a cheat, since the exploit will be in C, but it can appear to be in Python.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it